# Why am i getting error in java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package for_loops;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class add_digits_of_a_number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int rem, sum=0;
        for(;x>0; x =x/10)
                {   
                rem = x%10;
                sum = sum + rem;
                }
                System.out.println("Added digits of a number is" + sum);
    }

}
```

why i cant run my code without Suppress and my my import

```
java.util.Scanner is not working

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

i tried to suppress the Scanner and my expectation is not to suppress

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: yellow curly lines come

Comment: This is IDE-dependent; IntelliJ doesn't balk at this.  Also too, it doesn't look like there's any error with the scanner itself - you may have a typo with the output but that's about it.